# TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined, Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to filter a sparse array with many empty elements and null references, I keep getting this error(TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined), I'm not sure what exactly is causing the error and how to solve it. Here is my code.

```
    sparseArray = this.props.data;
    var CleanArray = sparseArray.filter(function (el) {
        return el != null;
    });
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is with `sparseArray` itself not being defined, not with the array being sparse - it seems there is no array at all at that `.data` property.

Comment: Which means, this.props.data is going undefined. Try printing it to the console and see what it contains.

Comment: try `console.log(this.props.data)` and post the result

Comment: I think you have to declare sparseArray. Can you please write down whole function here?

Comment: sparse array has been defined here is the whole module

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap it in the if statement like `(if this.props.data)` then declare the var. If you're fetching data from the network, that will take longer to come than the actual app being rendered.

Other thing you can do is to set defaultProps on your component to an empty array. That will prevent your app from crashing.

```
YOUR_COMPONENT_NAME.defaultProps = {
  data: []
};
```